# Нужно, чтобы при выборе одного варианта из QComboBox менялся текст в QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Изучаю PyQt5, нужно, чтобы при выборе одного варианта из `QComboBox` менялся текст в `QLabel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QComboBox::textActivated(const QString &text)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется, когда пользователь выбирает элемент в поле со списком. Текст элемента передается. Обратите внимание, что этот сигнал отправляется, даже если выбор не изменен. Если вам нужно знать, когда выбор действительно изменится, используйте сигнал currentIndexChanged() или currentTextChanged().
>
> textActivated была введена в Qt 5.14.

```
self.combo.textActivated.connect(self.label.setText)
```

---

Для версии меньше Qt 5.14.

> void QComboBox::activated(int index)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется, когда пользователь выбирает элемент в поле со списком. Индекс элемента передан. Обратите внимание, что этот сигнал отправляется, даже если выбор не изменен. Если вам нужно знать, когда выбор действительно изменится, используйте сигнал currentIndexChanged() или currentTextChanged().

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.combo.addItems(["Hello", "World", "?"])
        
        # textActivated была введена в Qt 5.14.
        # self.combo.textActivated.connect(self.onActivated) 
        
        self.combo.activated.connect(self.onActivated)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def onActivated(self):
        text = self.combo.currentText()
        self.label.setText(text)
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Noob пожалуйста